# VBA Can't pass "=IF()" into Range().Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to construct a formula to be inserted into many cells of a dynamically sized table in a sheet. This evaluated to `String` can be passed to `MsgBox` without problem:

```
Tmp2 = "=IF(" & Worksheets(Sh).Range("H9").Offset(i, 0).Address & _
       " = """";0;DAYS(" & Worksheets(Sh).Range("H9").Offset(i, 0).Address & _
       ";" & Worksheets(Sh).Range("G9").Offset(i, 0).Address & "))"
MsgBox Tmp2
```

MsgBox

[image]

But when I try to use it in a `.Formula` property like this:

```
Sheets("Temp").Range("I9").Offset(i, 0).Formula = Tmp2
```

I get this error:

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what Wxcle are you using ? what is `DAYS` function ?

Comment: You need to use [FormulaLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) with `;` parameter delimiters.

Comment: @Comintern That helped. Thank you! Can you explain in an answer what was happening and why it helped? PS: i was using `;` in my formula. The formula was tested manually before using in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is given that 'Sh' is a number in a variable. 
I noticed that also on computers with a different country setting, using ";" in formulas, the formulas work with ",".

```
Tmp2 = "=IF(" & Worksheets(Sh).Range("H9").Offset(i, 0).Address & _
       " = """",0,DAYS(" & Worksheets(Sh).Range("H9").Offset(i, 0).Address & _
       "," & Worksheets(Sh).Range("G9").Offset(i, 0).Address & "))"
MsgBox Tmp2
Worksheets("Temp").Range("I9").Offset(i, 0).Formula = Tmp2
```

Comment: My locale is English. The formula in this string, if entered manually, is working fine. If i remove first `=` sign from the string, everything works fine except the formula isn't parsed (due to missing `=`). `Sh` is `String` and `Worksheets(Sh).Name` returns the sheet name i'm expecting.

Comment: right, so either you want to use .Formula but then with ',' or you use .FormulaLocal if used with ';' .